# In Ruby/Rails, how can I create one column in a table based on the value of two other columns in the same table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a Reddit type app where the order of a list depends on a combination of the number of upvotes a link has and the created date.  My plan is to create a new column in my "Links" table that combines "created_date" and "upvotes" into a "Rank Value" and then sort the list by the "Rank Value".

Is this the right approach?  If so, how do I create this table column using ActiveRecord?

Comment: Take a look at the [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) api, particularly `before_save`.

Comment: You may not need a new column. If the combination is straightforward enough, why not a model method that would return the result. Like in @post.rank_value, where #rank_value is a method implementing the combination.

Now it depends on how you intend to combine the two columns (e.g. most recent or least recent date first?). Once you know what combination, it looks straightforward.

Comment: @EricPlaton it might be difficult to sort if you implement it as a method.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  Yes, my problem with using a method is that I need to order a list by the value.  I am pulling the list as an array into a block...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I believe a method is more appropriate when dealing with dynamic data. As mentioned now on this thread, the rank value evolves over time. Once again, implementation will depend on the actual combination. The load of the target site may also be influencing the implementation: A small to moderate load could be handled by simple approaches, like recalculating the rank for all each time (yuk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a meta attribute that is used purely for display purposes, creating a method that will generate it on the fly would be appropriate.

If you want to use it for sorting your objects as well, it's better to store it in a column.  Hopefully, it doesn't depend on things like the current time, and only on its other attributes:

```
before_save :calculate_rank

def calculate_rank
  self.rank = self.upvotes + self.clicks * 5;
end
```

Unfortunately, for your use case you specifically said your column depends on the creation date, probably in terms of "how fresh is it" -- a moving target.

You can solve this two ways: by constantly increasing the `rank` values for newer links indefinitely, or by putting items into time buckets and updating them periodically (degrading their scores when the day or week ends, perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

You can create methods in your model such as "rank_value" which would sort by your criteria and just call Model.rank_value